# encryption from char to int

Tags: c++, encryption

i'am writing some encryption program in c++, and when i start it then console print only one char, and decryption don't work, when i do encryption / decryption then program not doing that with numeric numbers of nn, he do that with hes adress. sorry for my english.

```
// Var
std::string text = "string";
const char *nn = text.c_str();

// Encryption
int x = (int(nn));
x = x * 3 - 100 * 2;
cout << "Numerical numbers: " << x << endl;
cout << "String: " << (char(x)) << endl;

// Decryption
x = (x - 100 * 2) / 3;
cout << "Numerical numbers: " << x << endl;
cout << "String: " << (char(x));
```

Comment: you are encrypting address of text, not text itself

Comment: I am reading a question on stack overflow but there seems to be no question.

Comment: And when you need help, you need to post more about the problem than it "Don't work".

Comment: i know that for addres, but what to do.

Comment: BTW in you decryption `x = (x - 100 * 2) / 3;` should be `x = (x + 100 * 2) / 3;`

Comment: NathanOliver try this, and you will be see that is right

     int x = 26;

     cout << "original " << x << endl;

     x = x * 3 + 100 * 2;

     cout << "encrypted " << x << endl;

     x = (x - 100 * 2) / 3;

     cout << "decrypted " << x << endl;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have restrictions that you have to use the formula `x * 3 - 100 * 2` for encryption/decryption, I suggest you to use [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    // Var
    std::string text = "string", encrypt, decrypt;
    
    // Encryption
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        encrypt += text[i] ^ '1';
    }

    // Decryption
    for (int i = 0; i < encrypt.length(); i++)
    {
        decrypt += encrypt[i] ^ '1';
    }
    
    std::cout << "original text: " << text << std::endl << "encrypted text: " << encrypt << std::endl << "decrypted text: " << decrypt;
}
```

The output of the above code would be:

> original text: string
>
> encrypted text: BECX_V
>
> decrypted text: string

[Here](http://ideone.com/VmynRE) is an working example of the above code.

Comment: Note that XOR with a single character/digit is nice for toy encryption. Don't use it for anything else.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Definitely agree with you. I was just showing how it can be done, more of like a `hello world` program but for encryption. :)

Comment: OK, but hello world cannot be easily abused. Encryption is abused all the time. Note that XOR with the *character* 1 doesn't result in printable text (I posted a code XOR'ed with byte value 1, which is much safer and still unreadable).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yeah, you kind of confused me there with cipher text. You are most welcome to edit my post with better answer which is safer. :)

Comment: Nah, somebody would just post a plaintext with a `~` character to annoy me.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I tried decrypting using numbers `1-9` and some alphabets but it didn't work so I gave up ;). Talking about abusing encryption though, I am new and want to learn more in security side, do you have any recommendations of newbie?

Comment: The best course so far was [Crypto I](https://www.coursera.org/course/crypto) but beware that it is a university level course. And Crypto II will probably only be given post-mortem, it keeps shifting to a later date.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes thanks for the link. I am signing up for that course.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would like to encrypt every characters of this:

```
std::string text = "string";
```

In this case you will need a vector of integers instead of a single int, to store every encoded character:

```
std::vector<int> encrypted;
```

Since you know what will be the final size of the vector, you can prepare the vector beforehand to allocate the necessary space, but this is optional:

```
encrypted.reserve(text.size());
```

Than you have to go through the characters one by one, encode them and put them to the vector:

```
for(auto &ch : text) {
    int x = ch * 3 - 100 * 2;
    encrypted.push_back(x);
}
```

The resulting vector can be printed this way:

```
cout << "Numerical numbers: ";
for(auto x : encrypted) { cout << x << ", "; }
cout << endl;
```

The decryption is analogous:

```
std::string decrypted;
decrypted.reserve(encrypted.size());
for(auto &x : encrypted) {
    char ch = (x + 100 * 2) / 3;
    decrypted += ch;
}
```